# Keep attached screen session alive and waiting for more commands to enter from detached screens

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I had this idea of a script that I was trying to make come to light. I want one main process that is running and keeping track of subprocesses running in the background. I decided to go with screen for my implementation, and I can run the `main.sh` in attached mode, with the subcommands all running in detached. I can also send text to the `main.sh` once each sub-process has hit their point. However, i want the main script to be running until all sub-processes finish (accomplished), but I want it to be updating what it is printing out to the user. I currently have the main process doing:

```
while screen -list | grep -q process-1 || screen -list | grep -q process-2 || screen -list | grep -q process-3; do
  sleep 1
done
```

which works perfectly as the main loop, but any data i send to that process just prints out like text, not like a command. Is there a way I can keep a screen session alive and receiving more commands/variables?

I currently plan on sending data from the sub-process like `screen -S main -X stuff "PROCESS_1=FINISHED"` and the main will keep trying to grab the variable `PROCESS_1` to get it's status.

I can't just get the result of the sub-process either, as for at least one of the commands i plan on it running continuously, but I want to let the main-process know when it has hit a certain point. I was also tinkering with the idea of using file descriptors but I had issues getting that working in detached mode.

Is this possible and I haven't just used/found the right command? Do i need to somehow use another screen as a like a data layer so that the main layer just prints out to the user?

For completeness, here is the current setup:

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

screen -S process-1 -dm ./process-1.sh
screen -S process-2 -dm ./process-2.sh
screen -S main -m ./main.sh
```

**main.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

while screen -list | grep -q process-1 || screen -list | grep -q process-2; do
  sleep 1
done
```

**process-1.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while [[ count -ne 5 ]]; do
  ((count+=1))
  sleep 5
done

screen -S main -X stuff "PROCESS_1=FINISHED"
```

**process-2.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

count=0
while [[ count -ne 3 ]]; do
  ((count+=1))
  sleep 5
done

screen -S main -X stuff "PROCESS_2=FINISHED"
```

Thanks for any advice you can provide.

EDIT:
Something along these lines is the end goal, like Vue.js, a constant screen that updates whenever changes are made (or in this case processes end)
[image]

Comment: "but any data i send to that process just prints out like text, not like a command" — that's because your `main.sh` does not accept commands at all. it'll work if `main.sh` is entering some interactive mode.

Comment: what's your purpose? what problem are you solving?

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells some new developers were waiting for logs and such in a singular script file to know when the process was done. I've now split it up into a subprocess that runs alongside, and they have gotten confused as to when stuff is done. I think it would be cool to move both scripts to the back, and keep almost a bash GUI screen that shows the dev when each of the scripts has finished, updating the screen in real time

Comment: it would be much easier for the main script to detect if other scripts have completed.